# How to get secret key for reading JWT in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am doing a simple spring boot app, I already did the login method which creates the JWT signed with a secret key. The secret key is autogenerated each time I run the app in the SecurityConfig class. Now what I want to do is get the token from any request and verify the role of the user (which I implemented using a simple Enumeration with 3 different type of users) to see if that role is authorized or not to do the request. I have seen some people writing the secret key in the application.properties and accessing it with the @Value annotation, however because the secret key is autogenerated, I cannot save it in the application.properties. I know storing it in application.properties is not safe, but its just a project i'm doing to improve my knowledge, not really trying to be super safe here. Any tips on how to inject/get the secret key for reading any jwt?

Here is the method that creates the secret key in the SecurityConfig class

```
    @Bean
    public SecretKey secretKey() {
        SecretKey secretKey = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
        byte[] encodedKey = secretKey.getEncoded();
        String encodedKeyBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedKey);

        System.out.println("Secret Key (Base64): " + encodedKeyBase64);

        return secretKey;
    }
```

Which is then passed for the constructor of the JwtAuthFilter

```
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthFilter jwtAuth() {
        return new JwtAuthFilter(secretKey());
    }
```

Here is what I had planned for reading the JWT in the controller for creating buildings (edificio = building its just in spanish)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="tpo_apis/edificios")
public class EdificioController {

    @Autowired
    private EdificioService edificioService;
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private SecretKey secret;

    @PostMapping(path ="/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEdificio(@RequestBody EdificioModel edificio, @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String token) throws Exception {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(secret) // secret should be the secret key to read the token
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
                .getPayload();

        System.out.println(claims.getSubject());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(edificioService.createEdificio(edificio), HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

And here is how I did the creation of the JWT although I dont think it really matters.

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody UsuarioModelDTO credentials) {
        // Validar las credenciales aquí (puedes usar Spring Security u otros
        // mecanismos)
        UsuarioModel usuario = this.usuarioService.findUsuario(credentials.getUsuario(), credentials.getPassword());
        if (usuario != null) {
            // Crear el token JWT
            String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .subject(credentials.getUsuario()).issuedAt(new Date())
                    .claim("rol", usuario.getTipoUsuario())
                    .issuedAt(new Date())
                    .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_MIN * 60 * 1000))
                    .signWith(secretKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your secret in `.env` file and put a placeholder in `application.properties`.

1. Put `.env` file in your project root.
2. Add line `SECRET_KEY=somekey`
3. Adjust `application.properties` to contain next properties:

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
jwtKey=${SECRET_KEY}
```

4. Get key in application via `@Value('${jwtKey}')

After this, Spring will take your key from `application.properties` and goes down to `.env` file.

This `.env` file is stored only on your computer, do not share it across the Internet.

Also with this approach any developer can provide its own secret key and run your app.

**RECOMENDATIONS:**

- Move as much properties as you can to `.env` file. It will make your app more configurable without rebuilding (for example when use Docker)

Comment: But if the key is generated randomly each time I run the app how do I know what to store in the .env file?

Comment: do not generate new key every time, store secret and generate key based on this secret `Key key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtProperties.getSecret().getBytes());`